# In VB.NET, how do I get the sum of all items in a listbox without taking a String

Tags: vb.net, listbox, sum

I have a program that needs to calculate the total amount from the Dvd's that I put into my shopping cart and their prices. I can put the items into my shopping cart and it shows up in the list box like this.

```
Terminator  12.59
Elf         12.99
```

And so on. I have been trying to just take the sum of those numbers for quite some time and I keep getting errors. I just need to pull the numbers from the listbox and be able to add them and use them when I check out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
`Private Sub calcButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles calcButton.Click
```

`cartTotal.Text = Array.ConvertAll(shopCart.Items.Cast(Of String).ToArray, Function(s) CInt(s)).Sum.ToString`

The error message I get is

```
 An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll Additional information: Conversion from string "Terminator  12.59" to type 'Integer' is not valid.
```

Comment: Show what you tried and describe what happened when you ran your code.

Comment: @SteveSmith - Please edit your question to include your code samples within code blocks, so they display correctly, instead of posting it as comments.

Comment: If your list box has all of the other text other than a number on each line you're going to have to write logic to get each number out of the given line. You could split each line at space but I'm not sure of your requirements or full input at this point.

Comment: Use objects and then simply sum the price of each item

Comment: @SteveSmith What's the type of each item? Is it string or it's a custom class?

Comment: Use the routine that loads the "shopping cart" to calculate the total in the cart. Not a great practice to scrape data from the GUI to do calculations.